# Problem to Connecting to AWSCodeCommit through Git using SSH Key

Tags: git, ssh-keys, aws-codecommit

The follwing command fails to connect to the EC2 instance:

```sh
$ ssh git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
no such identity: /c/Users/KarthiK/c/Users/KarthiK/.ssh/kk-code-commit: No such file or directory
APKAUTAVO7YATKGOPVVL@git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 2):

An `ssh xxx` command (as opposed to `ssh user@server`) would only work if you have a `/c/Users/KarthiK/.ssh/config` with in it:

```
Host git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
   Hostname it-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
   User APKAUTAVO7YATKGOPVVL
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/kk-code-commit
```

Take a second look at IdentityFile: I suspect in your case it is incorrect, considering "`$HOME`" (`/c/Users/KarthiK`) is repeated twice (`/c/Users/KarthiK/c/Users/KarthiK/.ssh/kk-code-commit`)

Replace it with `IdentityFile c/Users/KarthiK/.ssh/kk-code-commit`, and it should work better.